# What is the logic to re-order and insert at the top items in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I want to do is be able to let the user re-order (not sort) the items in a UITableView. In other words, change the order in what each item was entered, for instance the most common behavior is to show the first item entered into a table at the top but the user may want to see the last item at the top instead to verify what he/she entered.

What is the most common logic to accomplish this behavior?

Here is the code I'm using to enter my data to the table.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBAction func enter(sender: AnyObject?) {
         itemList.append(newItem)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let data = itemList[indexPath.row]
        cell.displayPrice!.text = String(data.basePrice)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I know I would probably need to change the way I'm inserting my items if the user re-orders the table, something like...

```
    var insertAtTop = false
    @IBAction func enter(sender: AnyObject?) {
        if insertAtTop{
           itemList.insert(newItem, atIndex: 0)
       }else{
          itemList.append(newItem)
      }
    }
```

It now inserts the items at the top but, of course, this doesn't re-order the items in the array `itemList`.

Has anyone done something like this?

I guess I could just have an `Insert At Top` option and clear the table to start new but the user would loose any item already entered.

[image]

Comment: you have successfully added the item in your array but you want to show it at the top in the tableView. Is that your issue?

Comment: No, I'm actually able to add new items at the top, my issue is how to reorder existing items and add new ones at the top.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you changing the order (with code) or is the user changing the order (by dragging and dropping cells)?

Comment: In my example and for testing purposes I'm using a button to reorder but eventually it will be with a switch in the settings view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the user to sort chronologically the data shown in a table, it's probably best to save a timestamp (e.g. `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`) along with each piece of data that's in the table and then `filter` the data source array by ascending or descending timestamp value.

```
dataSource.sort() { previous, next in
    previous < next // Ascending
}

dataSource.sort() { previous, next in
    previous > next // Descending
}
```

Comment: That sounds a little more complicated than what I anticipated. I was thinking to have a second array where I would add the existing items and reverse the order and then show the values of the new array.

Comment: Using a second array to store the sorted items is not a good idea because then you also need a variable that indicates the array's order (normal or reverse).